# Equivalent of file_transfer()?

Tags: 8

I am porting a Drupal 7 module to Drupal 8; it has a call to `file_transfer($uri, $headers)`. What's the equivalent Drupal 8 code for this?

Comment: When in doubt, check the api.drupal.org code and/or check Drupal core change records (https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/published/drupal). See https://www.drupal.org/node/1957078

Comment: @AyeshK Funny, I searched for file_transfer in change records and no results came up. Just tried again, same thing. Barinder, also check out the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/introduction.html) on the subject

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that_awesome_function() with 5-6 lines gets replaced by a 5-6 level deep namespaced 50kb symfony component the very next day ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `file_transfer` was removed in favor of `BinaryFileResponse`.

> Symfony has a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse`
>   class that can be used to deliver files through PHP to the client. It
>   also supports `X-Sendfile` and `X-Accel-Mapping` via
>   BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader().
>
> file_transfer() has been dropped in favor of that.
>
> Drupal 7:
>
> ```
> <?php return file_transfer($uri, $headers); ?>
> ```
>
> Drupal 8:
>
> ```
> <?php 
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse; ...
> return new BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers); 
> ?>
> ```

When looking for exact replacements and changes in D8, check the relevant api.drupal.org doc page and [change records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/published/drupal). I find it really comprehensive and has almost every change.

On a side note, I would reevaluate the module code if it happens for you to `file_trasnfer()` a file. Entire menu system was replaced with Symfony components and I think the odds are, you are still using the old system if it happens to `file_transfer()` or use some request-response thing in the site.